# batch script to transfer the file to the server after login into the another server

Tags: batch-file

I have one request for which i need to connect to windows machine and transfer the file to another windows machine. let say my machine is A, which i map the machine B (199.199.199.99), from the machine B user login only, i can access the machine C and transfer the file, how can i do it using the windows batch script.

File to transfer from A-> B ->C, please note C can be accessed only from B.

```
map machine
-----------
net use S: "\\199.199.199.99\Data" %password% /user:LONDON_DOMAIN\%userid%

:copy
Xcopy /F "A:\\FILE.CSV  "S:\FILE.CSV"
```

Comment: so to be clear, you want to transfer a file from A->B->C but C can only be accessed through B?

Comment: yes exactly yes, the file to be transferred is available in the machine A, I have the user and password credentials of machine B, which I map through batch script , but from scripting how to access machine C...